# Input borders getting cut off in Chrome on Windows 8

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, windows-8, html-input

The code below appears to be missing borders on the top of the first input and the left of both inputs.  But this ONLY happens on Chrome on Windows 8.1.  Using the exact same version of Chrome on Win2k8 and Win2k12 does not show the same issue.

Screenshot:
http://imgur.com/BUI5sOl

HTML:

```
<div id="universe">
  <div class="div1">
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="div2">
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.div2 {
  padding-top: 5px;
}

div.universe {
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tj2sLuyb/3/

**Edit: Just had someone else test it in Windows 8.1 and it looks fine for him. He suggested it might be a plugin, so I opened it in incognito mode, and it's only missing the top border on the second input.**

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This is what I see on:

Windows 8.1 Chrome 50

Comment: This was specifically done on a clean browser with no extensions...testing ENV.